# When will the raw data for the Developer Survey 2016 be available?

Tags: discussion, survey

I had heard at OSCON that the raw data for the Developer Survey 2016 would be available by early June.  Do you have an updated ETA?

Comment: I believe the current ETA is "in the next couple of weeks".

Answer (score 1):

It's here! (July 12, 2016, for the record.) On the Stack Overflow blog: [You Can Now Download Stack Overflow’s 2016 Developer Survey Data](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/you-can-now-download-stack-overflows-2016-developer-survey-data/?cb=1), which refers to the Shiny New [Research Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/research).

Comment: Also: thank you so much everyone for working on this. This is so cool!